# jQuery on() only works with first tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an application where div elements are dynamically added to the page. The page is also divided into jQuery UI tabs.

I have written a function using on() which applys a class of "selected" to whichever div is clicked on, allowing the user to perform other functions on the selected div.

My code works just fine for the first tab, but on the other tabs the class of "selected" is not being applied when I click on a div. What do I need to do so that this works with all of the tabs?

Here is my code:

```
//Select an individual content element by clicking on it
$(function() {
    $(".tabcontent").on("click", "div", function(event){
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected"); //remove "selected" class from any element that has it
        $(this).addClass("selected"); //add "selected" class to the div that was clicked
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML of the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab-1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab-2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab-3">Section 3</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div id="tab-1" class="tabcontent">
 Section Title:<input class="sectionTitle"></input></br>
 <div contenteditable="true">blah blah</div>
 </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tabcontent">
 Section Title:<input class="sectionTitle"></input>
 <div contenteditable="true">blah blah</div>
 </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tabcontent">
  Section Title:<input class="sectionTitle"></input>
  <div contenteditable="true">blah blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are the `.tabcontent` divs being dynamically added or the divs inside them ?

Comment: Ca be this $("body").on("click", ".tabcontent div", function(event) ?

Comment: Works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aek99/)

Comment: @PatsyIssa the 3 .tabcontent divs are there when the page loads, but the user can also create additional tabs dynamically

Comment: @Jon check my comment and give a try to it

Comment: `</br>` is an invalid tag/element

Comment: IS there a parent wrapper for the `.tabcontent` elements?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the parent wrapper is the div with id #tabs as shown in the html above

Answer (score 0):

This code will work on all tabcontent classes including those created dynamically after page load

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".tabcontent", function(event){
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected"); //remove "selected" class from any element that has it
        $(this).addClass("selected"); //add "selected" class to the div that was clicked
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't seem to work at all, my code worked on the first tab only, this doesn't work on any tabs

Answer (score 0):

You may try it using following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabcontent").on("click", function(event){
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected"); //remove "selected" class from any element that has it
        $(this).addClass("selected"); //add "selected" class to the div that was clicked
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this demo :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/Srykc/9/)

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
  // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
  // which tab is active and it's associated content
  var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

  // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
  // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
  $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
  $active.addClass('active');
  $content = $($active.attr('href'));

  // Hide the remaining content
  $links.not($active).each(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
  });

  // Bind the click event handler
  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    // Make the old tab inactive.
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    // Update the variables with the new link and content
    $active = $(this);
    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

    // Make the tab active.
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();

    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tab1'>
    <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab2'>
    <p>This is the 2nd tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab3'>
    <p>And this is the 3rd tab.</p>
  </div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
* {padding:0; margin:0;}

            html {
                background:url(/img/tiles/wood.png) 0 0 repeat;
                padding:15px 15px 0;
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size:14px;
            }

            p, h3 { 
                margin-bottom:15px;
            }

            div {
                padding:10px;
                width:600px;
                background:#fff;
            }
.tabs li {
                list-style:none;
                display:inline;
            }

            .tabs a {
                padding:5px 10px;
                display:inline-block;
                background:#666;
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none;
            }

            .tabs a.active {
                background:#fff;
                color:#000;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $("#tabs").on("click", ".tabcontent", function (event) {
        //remove "selected" class from any element that has it
        $('.selected').removeClass("selected");
        //add "selected" class to the div that was clicked
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Fiddle to show it working, with a specific CSS to make it visible: http://jsfiddle.net/du6M2/

NOTE: Resist adding the event manager to the document or window if possible, hooking to a closer element (parent wrapper) is desirable from a performance standpoint, especially on larger or complex pages.

Comment: I'm actually trying to select to select the div within the .tabcontent wrapper. Should it be ".tabcontent > div" instead of ".tabcontent"?

Comment: Yes if you want that direct child, use `.tabcontent>div` or, give that div set a class and select that as an alternative to make it definitive. i.e. `.tabcontent>div.selectable`

Comment: This still only works in the first tab. I can see it is working in the fiddle so I'll have to figure out what's stopping it from working in my page